# Problem with GPU rendering : Radeon RX 470

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I need help about rendering in Blender, when I try to render using GPU it freezes and quits the program without any changes.

CPU render works well.

I'm using Radeon (TM) RX 470 Graphics.

Comment: Are you sure your AMD graphic card is supported in Blender? Here is a link where you can find anything you need about Blender and AMD Radeon cards https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Comment: does this happen also on a simple (default cube) scene? are you sure to have your operating system's (best/latest) drivers for the card?

Comment: I tried using it on cube and it took some time, but it was slower than on CPU.

Comment: And i have drivers updated...

Comment: Looks like it works now, i used Driver Booster program and it made some updates